# Could you confirm the existence or not of Matlab 64 bit?

Tags: 64-bit

Could you confirm the existence or not of Matlab 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196885/running-on-32-or-64-bit-matlab) would imply existence.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm its existence, I have it running on my 64-bit Windows XP machine right now, on my 64-bit Mac OS X machine at home